# Visual Studio 2013 Installer Project run after finish option

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, installation

Using the Visual Studio 2013 Installer Project Extensions (https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d) it is possible to create a simple installer. One common option in an installer is an option at the and like "Start this application when install completes".

Is it possible to do this with the Installer Project Extensions and if so how?

Comment: have you found a solution ?

Comment: No, i don't think it's possible.